# Displaying The Println of a void function in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing

If I got a void function like the following...

```
public void OutputString()
{
      System.out.println("This is my string...");
}
```

How can I call this function and add it's output to a JLabel? I tried something like the following but it didn't work...

```
JLabel myLabel=new JLabel(String.valueof(MyClass.OutputString()));
```

Comment: The method doesn't output anything -- it's void, and so you cannot easily get the String since it just goes to standard output. It is possible to re-direct the standard output, but that would be too much needless trouble. Better to create a method that returns a String, and simply put that String into your JLabel via `setText(...)`. Note that your question smells to me as being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), one where you're asking about a fixing a specific solution when the overall approach to the problem is wrong. Better to tell us the details of your problem.

Comment: Sir @HovercraftFullOfEels I did know that I should make the function return a string or an array of chars. But the homework requires otherwise. In addition, I didnot want to post all the code I'm working on since it's about 100 lines of code. So I just wanted to ask while providing a sample a talk about. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Somewhere one of your assumptions about what you're supposed to be doing is way off since your approach is not a viable one. Better to post your actual requirements and more pertinent code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the function return something other than void, like a String.

Also you can't call OutputString() on MyClass unless it is static. You need an object reference.

Alternatively you could use a class variable to hold the string value and then either make it public or have a public method to get the value.

Unfortunately your code demonstrates a lack of understanding of the fundamentals of how the language works. I'd recommend reviewing the basics, they're everything.